# Arduino DMX Shield Issue

Tags: arduino, dmx512

I have bought this shield:

http://www.cqrobot.wiki/index.php/DMX_Shield_for_Arduino-CQR0260

I can see this reference: CTC-DRA-10-R2

I did not manage to make it work.

I want to control a lamp through DMX cable. In order to make the light, i need to set 100 value on channels 11 and 14.
I have tried this lamp with a computer and an USB to DMX converter. It works fine.

I am working with an Arduino Mega.

I have tried 3 librairies: DmxSimple and DmxMaster, (which are the same) and Conceptinetics.

Here is my first test with Conceptinetics:

I have put the switch like this:

```
EN/ (with a bar) during program update, then EN
DE
TX-UART
RX-UART
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <Conceptinetics.h>

DMX_Master        dmx_master (100,2);

void setup()
{
    dmx_master.enable ();
}

void loop()
{
    dmx_master.setChannelValue(11,100);
    dmx_master.setChannelValue(14,100);
    delay(100);
}
```

The lamp is not lightning

Now, i have made a second test with DmxMaster (i have made a third test with DmxSimple, it is exactly the same):

```
EN
DE
TX-I0
RX-I0
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <DmxMaster.h>

void setup()
{
    DmxMaster.usePin(4);
    DmxMaster.maxChannel(32);
}

void loop()
{
    DmxMaster.write(11, 100);
    DmxMaster.write(14, 100);
    delay(100);
}
```

The lamp is not lightning too.

So i do not understand the problem.

I have tried in each test to set Arduino Mega 's pin 2 to LOW or HIGH but it does not change anything.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a very short dmx cable. It works!

Answer (score 0):

My code uses pin(3). Try making the first parameter in your DmxMaster.write() 1, 2 or 3. I think they are the only values you can use 1 being red 2 green and 3 blue. That works for me!